# How to handle different microphone gains in different android phones?

Tags: android, signal-processing, microphone

I am developing an `android application` in which I have to record an audio from an android phone and find the power of a specific frequency using `Goertzel algorithm`. Using that power value, I am making some decisions regarding some secret messages sent through the audio.

In order for this application to be used in a variety of android phones, I need to make sure that the microphone gains of all the phones are the same. But unfortunately, different phones have different gains.

> > (Sony phones have very small gains and Samsung, HTC phones have very large gains). Is there a way to set a common gain to the microphones through android?

One other option is, I can record the audio to the full length and normalize it. However, I cannot do this because, I am doing this processing in real time, i.e. I have to do the processing for each and every frame received from the audiorecorder object and calculate the power value, the app cannot wait until the end of the audio to decide the message.

So, if possible, please suggest me some methods I can try to overcome this.

Comment: You probably want to implement some sort of [AGC algorithm](https://duckduckgo.com/Automatic_gain_control).

Comment: Thanks. More on AGC in,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AutomaticGainControl.html

I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi, I have bumped to a similar problem. have you found a solution for your problem? Regards